# How can efficiently download a large list of tickers from Yahoo Finance?

Tags: python, r, download, yahoo-finance

I have a really large list of tickers for which I want to download financial data using Yahoo finance.

I am now working with python, but R solutions are also welcomed.

Here is the piece of python code and the excel file with the tickers is also attached:

```
import yfinance as yf
from yahoofinancials import YahooFinancials

# get tickers 
mf_tickers = pd.read_excel('tickers_mutual_funds.xlsx')

# download data 
tickers = mf_tickers.Symbol
funds_financials = YahooFinancials(tickers)

data = funds_financials.get_historical_price_data(start_date='2019-01-01', 
                                                  end_date='2019-12-31',
                                                  time_interval='weekly')
```

The problem is that it takes ages,like hours, in my computer to load this size of data.

What is a better and more efficient way to load these data? As said, I am happy with both python or R solutions.

File to load:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/1l41tk8gxzqvutd/tickers_mutual_funds%20copy.xlsx?dl=0

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd offer up a package called [yahooquery](https://github.com/dpguthrie/yahooquery), with the **DISCLAIMER: I am the author of the package**.

Here's how you could do it:

```py
from yahooquery import Ticker

mf_symbols = pd.read_excel('tickers_mutual_funds.xlsx')
symbols = mf_tickers.Symbol.tolist()

tickers = Ticker(symbols, asynchronous=True)

data = tickers.history(start='2019-01-01', end='2019-12-31', interval='1wk')
```

For the most part, the history method will return a `pandas.DataFrame`. However, there's lots of ticker symbols in your list that weren't around in 2019 or just don't have data altogether.  So, it will be a dictionary, with each symbol as a key.

Here's how you can get to a single dataframe:

```py
# Add symbol column to each dataframe
for key in data:
    if isinstance(data[key], pd.DataFrame):
        data[key]['symbol'] = key

# Concat all dataframes
df = pd.concat([data[k] for k in data if isinstance(data[k], pd.DataFrame)])
```

Here's some stats from when I ran the same function above:

- Runtime: ~5 minutes
- Valid Symbols (symbols that returned data): 19,415
- Total rows in dataframe: 1,008,180
- Symbols with no data: 6,571

Comment: Do we know the reason that some tickers don't have data?

Comment: I haven't checked all of them, but for the most part it looks like they fall in two categories:  no data is available because they weren't active during that particular timeframe or they're moneymarket funds.

Comment: your package is good. I downloaded the rest with yahoo financial module. I recommend expanding the functionality of your package, but trying other modules when data is missing from some tickers and then return the final results.